# How do I pass children index number to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, indexing, ecmascript-6

My Data looks like the below.

```js
      const data = {
      main: {
        88: {
          issues: [
            {
              id: 1

            },
            {
              id: 3
            },
            {
              id: 4
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    };
```

I am looping through `data.main` and then passing some data to the child component like this.

```js
       {Object.values(data.main).map((key) => {

         <Issues
            id={key}
            issueIndex={XXX}
            {...this.props}
          />

        }
```

But I also want to pass an index of all issues to the child element. So that I can number it from here.

My attemp inside jsx file below.

```js
   {Object.values(data.main).map((group, key) => {
    let issuesArr = group.issues;
     {issuesArr.map((value, index) => { index + 1; })}

             <Issue
                id={key}
                issueIndex={XXX}
                {...this.props}
              />

            }
```

I want to pass a number as `issueIndex` to the `<Issue />` I have no control of the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is happening because your `issuesArr.map` isn't doing anything. Change your code to this:

```
{
  Object.values(data.main).map((group, key) => {
    let issuesArr = group.issues;
    {
      issuesArr.map((value, index) => {
          return (
             <Issue
               id={key}
               issueIndex={value.id}
               {...this.props}
             />
          )
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is right way to do this, however I would suggest changing the `issueIndex={index + 1}` prop to `issueIndex={value.id}` to retain the dataset's (potentially) unique id.

Comment: @MEnf agreed, made the change. Thanks.

Comment: no i am getting nothing in the loop when i do this? its empty - i dont know why because when i console it shows me the object.

Comment: put a console log on `value` inside `issuesArr.map` and see if things are logged